# How to display separate rows in histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I have a set of data that I've assigned to a variable named "data1". I know how to make a histogram of certain column, by `hist(data1$RT)`. But among the RT column, there are "high", "medium", and "low", 'Factor's', I want to make 3 separate histograms for each factor variable but can't figure out how to do this. Here's an example of the data:

```
  Frequency Prime_type  RT
1      high      prime 450
2      high      prime 460
3       med      prime 520
4       med      prime 430
5       low      prime 450
6       low      prime 420
```

I can display `hist(data1$RT)`, but how would I just display RT's 'high' or 'med' factors for example? I've tried a lot of things and am still stumped.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the data would display in columns, it's a little confusing to look at.

Comment: Basically, I know how to choose a column among some data and make a histogram of it, but within the column, I'd like to select a certain chunk. The three different rows are 'high, 'med' and 'low'.

Comment: Could you edit your question, instead of adding comments?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by faceting the plot with `ggplot2`. First, we modify df$Frequency to have the panels in order: high, med and low. Then we create the histogram specifying the breaks and using `facet_wrap` to divide the chart in panels. Note that we add the argument `right = TRUE` (right-closed and left-open intervals) to calculate the intervals as the `hist` function does.

```
library(ggplot2)
df$Frequency <- factor(df$Frequency, levels=unique(df$Frequency))
h <- ggplot(df, aes(x=RT), xlim=c(420,520)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(420, 520, by=20), col="white", right = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap( ~ Frequency) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(420, 520, by=20))
h
```

Output:

[image]

**Data**:

```
df <- structure(list(Frequency = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("high", "low", "med"), class = "factor"), Prime_type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "prime", class = "factor"), RT = c(450L, 
460L, 520L, 430L, 450L, 420L)), .Names = c("Frequency", "Prime_type", 
"RT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```